# ngModel is not working in select options inside a for loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add options in a html select inside a for loop. To get the selected option i am using [(ngModel)] but by default no option is selected.

Sample Code:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index">
        <td>
          <select id="status" [(ngModel)]="d.status" name="d.status" (change)="onStatusChange(i, d.id)">
            <option *ngFor="let o of statusArray" [ngValue]="o">{{o.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the component that I am using:

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
    statusArray;
    data;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusArray = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Testing"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Free Trial"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Active/Paying"
        }
    ];

    this.data = [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "status": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Testing"
            },
            "new": false
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "status": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Testing"
            },
            "new": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "status": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Free Trial"
            },
            "new": false
        }
    ];
  }

}
```

Output :

Here in the output i am getting the options in the list but default value is not selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
<option *ngFor="let o of statusArray" [ngValue]="o">{{o.name}}</option>
```

with:

```
<option *ngFor="let o of statusArray" [ngValue]="o.id">{{o.name}}</option>
```

`o` is an array, so no value exists for your option.

Comment: It didn't work for me .. I am still not able to see the default selected option

Comment: i need to check for the complete object not only for id .. so whenever any option is changed i should have the complete object in the model

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by default by using :

```
[(ngModel)]="d.status"
```

set the default value in d.status which you want to set.

Comment: d.status contains the default value...I am using ngfor in tr to get the data from the component and trying to display the status of particular record but by default it is showing blank .. check the output link that i have provided ..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was to make sure the name attribute of the select was different for each item.

Change

```
name="d.status"
```

to

```
name="d.status{{i}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you compare options to select by `compareWith` property, If you are using angular 4.

**HTML File :**

```
<select [compareWith]="byAnimal" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnimal">  
  <option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [ngValue]="animal">
    {{animal.type}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**TS File**

```
byAnimal(item1,item2){
  return item1.type == item2.type;
}
```

One of the best soltion from this [link](https://www.mbejda.com/angular-4-compare-with/)